# How to give page break in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, sql-server-2012, page-break

I am making a very simple report in SSRS. I am trying to do the following:

On page 1 display following text

```
THIS IS PAGE 1
```

On page 2 display following text

```
THIS IS PAGE 2
```

I added "Text" field in my report in which I have set the value field to "THIS IS PAGE 1". But I can't find any option to add page break after it. How do I give page break?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what is the purpose of having Page Break for you without any content.. 
but still i tried by adding a table on a report with one column and hide that and it works

Step 1

Create a DataSet with query (commandtext)

```
 Select 'A' AS GRP
 UNION
 Select 'B' AS GRP
```

Step 2

Insert a table & set DataSetName as created in step1

Step 3

Click on Table Group & press F4 to Set Page Break Properties value,
Set BreakLocation to Between & PageName to =Fields!GRP.Value (See screenshot for your Ref)

[image]
Step 4
From above Step you will see report break into 2 page as there are 2 records from query step 1.. Now next step is to Display Page Number for the insert PageHeader

Step 5

Insert Page Header with textbox expression value as

```
 ="THIS IS PAGE " &  CSTR(Globals!PageNumber)
```

Last but not least, Hide unexpected table columns (TextBox) as you just want to display Page Number or Page Header

Output of the report will be like

[image]