# SSRS Matrix Page Break of Column Group by WeekNumber

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-tablix

I have a similar problem with this one,
[SSRS Matrix Page Break of Column Groups](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22077269/ssrs-matrix-page-break-of-column-groups)

Is it really not possible to do this? Aren't there any other way aside from hiding the column group?

Answer (score 0):

If I am not wrong you are looking for output like Display Week 1 Record then in next row or in next page Display Week 2 Record or this can be generic to Display N week on each page.

I have answered to similar Question few months back. You can take reference to that [M X N Matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26758955/3198474)

Above example will give output like week per row .. next is to give page break

Click on Table Group & press F4 to Set Page Break Properties value, Set BreakLocation to Between & PageName to =Fields!GRP.Value

[Page Break](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25481411/3198474)

Comment: How about page break on column group? I have also tried adding a page break on my column group but not working, I'm trying to display Per Week Record on every page like this

EID      Monday    Tuesday     Wednesday  .................

The day names are group by Week No

Comment: no need set page break on column group.. just do a row group on week number then set page break on that. it will lead to create a separate page per week.